# Is no-asm option while building openssl discouraged?

Tags: compilation, openssl

I am looking at some old code in the product i am working on and it seems they have used no-asm option while compiling openssl. I read that with assembly routines openssl can perform faster. Then why using assembly subroutines while compiling openssl is discouraged. Is it related to FIPS guidelines?